# Exclamation Mark (!) in registry path

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I need to set `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog` to `1`.

I've managed to find the path to fusion, but don't see anything regarding `!EnableLog`

Does this exclamation bear any special significance? How do I set this value to `1`?

Comment: Do you have a problem creating the entry?

Comment: "I need to set HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog to 1" Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @AFH I added `!EnableLog` to the `Fusion` directory and set it to 1, but it didn't seem to have any effect, which is why I am wondering if I did something wrong

Comment: @DavidPostill it came from an error message generated by asp.net. I am having a binary compatibility problem with my run time compiled web pages that I am trying to debug, but I figured it was beyound the scope of this site

Comment: Maybe it was an error on the site which told about it, just as I suspect you made an error by missing a back-slash in the registry string you quote.

Comment: [c# - How to enable assembly bind failure logging (Fusion) in .NET - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When writing Registry paths as a single string, Microsoft's convention is to separate the key and value names with `!`. Therefore the instruction to "set `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog` to 1" means:

> Create a value named *EnableLog* in the key `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion` and set its data to **1**.